# How to use jenkins environment variable in Jenkinsfile if statement

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I am trying to use an if statement in my Jenkinsfile for multi branch pipeline project. For the sake of this question, assume I have a text file in my current directory called 'scan.txt'. The text file is generated with a bash command

```
echo "False" > scan.txt
```

So the only content is the string "False"

I set an arbitrary environment variable in my Jenkinsfile to the contents of scan.txt like so:

```
script {
    env.TEXT = readFile 'scan.txt'
}
```

If I do

```
echo "${env.TEXT}"
```

outside the script block then the jenkins console shows False for that step, as expected.

However, all of my attempts at checking if it is equal to "False" have failed. I have tried the following immediately after the script block:

```
if (env.TEXT.equals("False")) {
    //do something
}

if (env.TEXT.matches("False")) {
    //do something
}


if (env.TEXT == "False") {
    //do something
}
```

and none of them work. All of these conditions are boolean false. The documentation for the read file pipeline step states it returns a string of the file contents
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-readfile-code-read-file-from-workspace
so I'm not sure what's going on here. Does anyone have any insights?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that when you do `echo "False" > scan.txt` echo will leave a line break at the end of the file, you can se this if you echo `env.TEXT` in your pipeline script.

So what you need to do is use `String.trim()` before checking if it equals `False`, trim will remove all white spaces at the beginning and end. Additionally, the best way of testing if a string contains is to use `Boolean.parseBoolean()`, it does all the hard work for you.

Let's try this:

```
node {
    sh 'echo "False" > output.txt'
    def val = readFile 'output.txt'
    echo "${val}"
    echo "${val.trim()}"
    if (val.equals("False")) { // This will print No
        echo "Yes"
    } else {
        echo "No"
    }
    if (val.trim().equals("False")) { // This will print Yes
        echo "Yes"
    } else {
        echo "No"
    }
    if (!Boolean.parseBoolean(val)) { // This will print Yes
        echo "Yes"
    } else {
        echo "No"
    }
}
```

And on the output we get:

```
Started by user jon
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pl
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[pl] Running shell script
+ echo False
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] echo
False

[Pipeline] echo
False
[Pipeline] echo
No
[Pipeline] echo
Yes
[Pipeline] echo
Yes
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

As you can se, we have an extra line break when we do the first echo step. Also note that `Boolean.parseBoolean()` handles the string without any trimming.

Answer (score 2):

here is some cases, hope it will save time for some people:

```
node {

sh 'echo "False" > output.txt'
def val = readFile 'output.txt'
echo "${val}"
echo "${val.trim()}"
if ( "${val.trim()}" ==~ /False/ ) {
    echo "Match Yes trim"
} else {
    echo "Match No trim"
}

if ( "${val}" ==~ /(?ms)False/ ) {
    echo "Match Yes (?ms)"
} else {
    echo "Match No (?ms)"
}

if ( "${val}" ==~ /(?ms)False.*/ ) {
    echo "Match Yes (?ms).*"
} else {
    echo "Match No (?ms).*"
}

if ( "${val}" =~ /False/ ) {
    echo "Match Yes 1="
} else {
    echo "Match No 1="
}

}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo False
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] echo
False

[Pipeline] echo
False
[Pipeline] echo
Match Yes trim
[Pipeline] echo
Match No (?ms)
[Pipeline] echo
Match Yes (?ms).*
[Pipeline] echo
Match Yes 1=
```

Where (?ms) means multi line and s for dot matching new line in regex.

Note that `echo "False" >` will add newline to the file. This either needs to be trimmed or `echo -n` used.

Answer (score -1):

So it turns out if I use the condition

```
env.TEXT.contains("False")
```

then it works! It must be that readFile contains more than just "False" in its string.

Comment: This is a hack, the real solution has been given by Jon S.